# Conditional repeat or retry on Mono with webclient from Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, webclient, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want implement a **conditional repeat** on a `Mono` in WebFlux with `WebClient`. The situation is the following:

We have a rest service service that returns a generated document. The generation of this document is triggered from another service that gets called before this one. The document generation service needs between 10-30 seconds.

We want to check after 10 seconds if document (`Mono<Document>`) is generated. If so, all is fine. If not, repeat (or retry) after another 5 seconds and check if document is generated. And so on until (worst case) a timeout after 30 seconds.

Is this possible? Some (pseudo) code:

```java
return this.webClient
    .post()
    .uri(SERVICE_URL))
    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(docRequest))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Document.class)
    .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    .repeat5TimesWithDynamicTimeDelayUntil(!document.isEmpty())
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

`Mono` has two concepts for re-subscribing (and thus, re-triggering the request)

- *retry* = re-subscribe if the upstream completed with an exception
- *repeat* = re-subscribe if the upstream completed successfully

Each concept has multiple overloaded methods on `Mono` for different use cases.  Look for the `retry*` and `repeat*` methods.
For example, to retry a maximum number of times with no delay, use `retry(int numRetries)`.

More complex use cases are supported via the `retryWhen` and `repeatWhen` methods, as shown in the following examples.

#### retryWhen

To retry if the mono completed with an exception a maximum of 5 times with 5 seconds between each attempt:

```java
// From reactor-core >= v3.3.4.RELEASE
import reactor.util.retry.Retry;

this.webClient
        .post()
        .uri(SERVICE_URL)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(docRequest))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Document.class)
        .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
        .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
```

The retry builder supports other backoff strategies (e.g. exponential) and other options to fully customize retries.

Note the `retryWhen(Retry)` method used above was added in reactor-core v3.3.4.RELEASE, and the `retryWhen(Function)` method was deprecated.
Prior to reactor-core v3.3.4.RELEASE, you could use the retry function builder from [reactor-extras](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#extra-repeat-retry) project to create a `Function` to pass to `retryWhen(Function)`.

#### repeatWhen

If you need to repeat on success, then use `.repeatWhen` or `.repeatWhenEmpty` instead of `.retryWhen` above.

Use the repeat function builder from [reactor-extras](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#extra-repeat-retry) project to create the repeat `Function` as follows:

```
// From reactor-extras
import reactor.retry.Repeat;

this.webClient
        .post()
        .uri(SERVICE_URL)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(docRequest))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Document.class)
        .filter(document -> !document.isEmpty())
        .repeatWhenEmpty(Repeat.onlyIf(repeatContext -> true)
                .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
        .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
```

You can also chain a `.retry*` with a `.repeat*` if you want to re-subscribe on both success or failure.

Comment: Well, i tried it and until one thing it works fine. It seems that delaySubscription is executed again in the repeat. So i am waiting 20secs until the backoff comes into game. Could that be? Will be pasting my code a little later....

Comment: Edited to move delaySubscription to after the retry/repeat so that the delay is not executed on each retry/repeat

Comment: Ok will try it again tomorrow and will give feedback. Thank you.

Comment: It works fine, thank you. One thing seems to be strange. If I would have configured the repeat handling the way that the time is shorter than there is a result from the Service (e.g. repeat.4times.a.4.secs.thenend and the service takes 20secs) the whole result will be a null value although theres a block() at the end....can someone explain that?

Comment: `.block()` will return null if the Mono completes empty, which is what happens if you're doing something similar to my second example.  The `Mono` will complete empty because the `.filter` filters out the value, and the `repeatWhenEmpty` condition no longer applies (i.e. it has timed out).

Comment: Is there a way to log that the retry is occurring?

Comment: @wild_nothing use `onErrorMap`

Comment: how to execute something when max retry has been reached?

Comment: Is it possible to throw an exception or log when `retryMax` or `timeout` met? How can we do that. thanks

Comment: Can I use retryWhen when invoking some endpoint returns nothing/empty list? I want to use retryWhen in case invoking my endpoint doesn't return anything (Mono.empty). My question is if in such a case retryWhen will be invoked too

Comment: @jeevjyotsinghchhabda Yes. See RetrySpec.onRetryExhaustedThrow

Comment: @Matley retry* only applies when an exception occurs.  To resubscribe when a Mono completes empty, use Mono.repeatWhenEmpty

Comment: @Phil Clay thank you for your response:) Can I have another question? I have a long chain of flatMap() etc.. Can I tell Webflux to repeat only some particular flatMap with calling my endpoint? My topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641880/webflux-repeatwhenempty-or-retrywhen

Comment: Is there any way to `log` when `retryWhen` is called & for how many times?

Comment: @Phil Clay Is there a way to long poll using block as well? I am trying to avoid making a for loop with web calls until I get the desired response

Comment: @GeorgianBenetatos Yes, use the retry or repeat operators as described in the answer and then block at the end.