# How Do I Generate Event Stream Every Time Variable Is Changed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, stream, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

**I want to send update every time the integer variable is changed**

```
@PutMapping
public void update() {
    integer = random.nextInt();
}

@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Integer> eventFlux() {
    Flux<Integer> eventFlux = Flux.fromStream(
            Stream.generate(() -> integer)
    );
    return Flux.zip(eventFlux, onUpdate()).map(Tuple2::getT1);
}

private Flux<Long> onUpdate() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question? are you getting any errors. Please explain your query clearly!

Comment: As the code stands now, It's sending events every second, I was wondering how do I send event only when the Variable value is changed. Thanks.

Comment: Please go through this link if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923326/conditional-repeat-or-retry-on-mono-with-webclient-from-spring-webflux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `FluxProcessor` to work as an:

- Upstream `Subscriber`; which you can use to add numbers to it:

```
    @PutMapping("/{number}")
    public void update(@PathVariable Integer number) {
        processor.onNext(number);
    }
```

- Downstream `Publisher` (`Flux`); which clients can subscribe to receive the numbers added:

```
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Integer> eventFlux() {
        return processor;
    }
```

The following is a full working example of this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer;

import reactor.core.publisher.DirectProcessor;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxProcessor;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebFlux
@RestController
public class EventStreamApp implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EventStreamApp.class);
    }

    private FluxProcessor<Integer, Integer> processor = DirectProcessor.create();

    @PutMapping("/{number}")
    public void update(@PathVariable Integer number) {
        processor.onNext(number);
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Integer> eventFlux() {
        return processor;
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-59589437)

Hope this helps.