# Webflux repeatWhenEmpty or retryWhen

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I use SpringBoot and reactive programming with Webflux.
I want to repeat some calling of my endpoint till data will be available (something will be returned).

I want to call `commandControllerApi.findById` until displayCommand will be returned with status `== SUCCESS`. How to tell Webflux that this part of my chain should be called for example 5 times because the data in my database should apper after 5-10 seconds...

I think the current code causes calling the whole chain again and not only the proper part of my chain (`.flatMap(commandResponse -> commandControllerApi.findById(commandResponse.getCommandId()))`)

My code:

```
public Mono<Boolean> validateCredentials(FlowConfCredentials flowCredentials, UUID agentId) {
    return securityService
        .getUser()
        .flatMap(
            user -> {
              Command command = new Command ();
              command.setAgentId(agentId.toString());
              command.setCommandType(COMMAND_TYPE);
              command.setArguments(createArguments());
              command.setCreatedBy(
                  user.getEmail());
              return commandControllerApi.saveCommand(command);
            })
        //       .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
      .flatMap(commandResponse -> commandControllerApi.findById(commandResponse.getCommandId()))
        .filter(displayCommand -> displayCommand.getStatus().equals(OaCommandStatus.SUCCESS))
        .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
//        .repeatWhenEmpty(
//            Repeat.onlyIf(repeatContext -> true)
//                .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofSeconds(5))
//                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
        .filter(
            commandResponse ->
                commandResponse.getStatus() != null
                    && commandResponse.getStatus().equals(CommandStatus.SUCCESS))
        .map(commandResponse -> true)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(false));
  }
```

And below is the method that is calling the metohd above:

```
 public Flux<CredConfiguration> saveCredentials(
      Mono<FlowConfCredentials> flowCredentials, UUID agentId) {
    return flowCredentials
        .filterWhen(cred -> validationService.validateCredentials(cred, agentId))
        .flatMapMany(
            flowConfCredentials -> {
              if (condition1()) {
                return caveCredentials(flowConfCredentials);
              }
              if (condition2()) {
                return saveCredentialsForUser(flowConfCredentials.getExistingCredentials());
              }
              return Flux.error(new EmptyConfigurationException(CREDENTIALS_MESSAGE));
            });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To only repeat the subscription to the mono returned by findById without resubscribing to the upstream saveCommand/getUser, move the filter/repeatWhenEmpty inside the flatMap that calls findById.

```java
public Mono<Boolean> validateCredentials(FlowConfCredentials flowCredentials, UUID agentId) {
    return securityService
        .getUser()
        .flatMap(
            user -> {
              Command command = new Command();
              command.setAgentId(agentId.toString());
              command.setCommandType(COMMAND_TYPE);
              command.setArguments(createArguments());
              command.setCreatedBy(
                  user.getEmail());
              return commandControllerApi.saveCommand(command);
            })
        .flatMap(saveResponse -> commandControllerApi.findById(saveResponse.getCommandId())
           .filter(findResponse -> findResponse.getStatus().equals(OaCommandStatus.SUCCESS))
           .repeatWhenEmpty(
                Repeat.onlyIf(repeatContext -> true)
                    .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))))
        .hasElement();
}
```

Comment: Hmm unfortunately commandControllerApi.findById is called only once...

Comment: To clarify, findById will only be _called_ once, but the mono returned by it will be re-subscribed for each repeat interval.  I've updated my answer to clarify this.
Therefore, ensure that the mono returned by findById will execute the api request for each subscription.  If it does not, you can wrap the findById call inside a Mono.defer to force findById to be _called_ for each subscription.

Comment: Hmmm maybe I don't understand something - that means that commandControllerApi.findById will be invoked only once but the mono returned by commandControllerApi.findById will be re-subscribed so the value will be returned anyway when some data will appear in my database?

Comment: It depends on how findById behaves.  Ideally it returns a Mono that will re-query your database for each subscription.  If so, then the code in my answer works as-is.   If findById does _not_ requery the database for each subscription, then you'll need to wrap the call to findById in a Mono.defer to force the findById method to be called for each subscription.

Comment: hmm commandControllerApi.findById invokes some endpoint from other service and returns Mono<Command>... 
What determines whether the method can be subscribed or not?? BUT you're right! After wrapping findById into Mono.defer(), findById is invoking many times!:   Mono.defer(() ->
                commandControllerApi
                    .findById(saveResponse.getCommandId())) With my previosu solution without Mono.defer() Im just testing in spock 5 * commandControllerApi.findById(_ as String) >> Mono.empty() but I have only 1 invocation

Comment: The author of the method that returns the Mono/Flux determines how the returned Mono/Flux behaves.  The best practice is to perform the "work" at subscription-time rather than up-front during assembly-time.  This allows re-subscription to re-perform the "work" so that retry/repeat work properly.  However, best practices are not always followed.

Comment: OK but how can I control if my method returning Mono allows re-subscription or not?

Comment: First, make sure that all the downstream publishers that your method relies on do their work at subscription time.  If any do not, then use Mono/Flux.defer when calling them.
Second, make sure you're not doing work in _your method_ at assembly-time. (Your example looks fine) Anything that you want to be able to be retried/repeated by callers of your method should occur at subscription-time.  I go over a little bit of this in my talk here... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCu73WVg8Ps

Comment: WOW thank you for all your explanations - you are a Reactor guru:) I will watch your lecture with pleasure, thanks!

Comment: "Repeat.onlyIf" -> I failed to figure out from where to import this. I am using reactor-core 3.5.8

Comment: Repeat.onlyIf is a reactor-addon, maybe most projects that use reactor already use it but I didn't: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.addons/reactor-extra